# Better way to check if textbox values are changed using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a textbox which keeps track of old data and verifies with new data on keyup event. But this works well for single field.

```
$(function() {
    var content = $('#myContent').val();

    $('#myContent').keyup(function() { 
        if ($('#myContent').val() != content) {
            alert('Content has been changed');
        }
    });
});
<input type="text" id="myContent" class="field1">
```

Say if there are multiple fields with the same class then how can we track the old data and verify with new data?

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways but below is one of the way to retain original value in `data` attribute and compare it with entered value on keyup event.

See below code

```js
$(function(){
  //store original value in data attribute
  $('input.field1').each(function(){
     $(this).data('original', $(this).val());
  });
  
  //set keyup event handler
  $('input.field1').on('keyup', function(){
     var changedValue = $(this).val();
     if(changedValue != $(this).data('original')) {
       console.log('Value changed');
     } else {
       console.log('Value same');
     }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="myContent1" class="field1" value="value1"><br>
<input type="text" id="myContent2" class="field1" value="value1"><br>
<input type="text" id="myContent3" class="field1" value="value1"><br>
<input type="text" id="myContent4" class="field1" value="value1"><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's something similar to the first answer but saves the original value when the user focuses on the input. There's also a [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pdxohb8a/).

```
$('.field1').on('focus', function() {
  $(this).data('value', $(this).val());
}).on('keyup', function() {
  if ($(this).data('value') != $(this).val()) {
    console.log('Content has changed');
  }
});
```